# Convert number format to simple number

Tags: php

i want to convert number like this in normal numbers

```
1,200.00 -> 1200
100.00 -> 100
1,000.00 -> 1000
1,345,490.00 -> 1345490
```

Is there a way to make that? with PHP

Comment: tried google? here you show us what you tried, we help with improving YOUR code

Comment: Use `str_replace()` to remove the commas.

Comment: now you give the solution that @Barnar gives in your question? using str_replace and round() would work: SHOW us YOUR code

Comment: rtm for the number_format function

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
$number = (int)strtr($string, array("," => "", " " => ""));
```

Comment: and what if its 2,500.75